# Cumulo city custom property in SCADA widget?

Tags: cumulocity

I would like to map a placeholder in a SCADA widget to a custom property that I put in my device via UpdateManagedObject. I can see the property using the API but it doesn't appear along native properties when I configure the widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible, although this feature to add non-native properties from managed objects was implemented in version [7.27.0](https://support.cumulocity.com/hc/en-us/articles/220786547-Cumulocity-7-27-release-notes).

Comment: Thanks Piotr, is this version already available? If not, when will it be?